# Listview without jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please help. I am trying to achieve the same style of jQuery Listview with only HTML and CSS.
I am almost there minus the space under each list element and also the border wrapping individual elements and not the whole list.

http://jsfiddle.net/6zs2V/

CSS Code:

```
    /* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
    .nav {
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        /*-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px 0px;*/
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        /*box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px 0px;*/
        /*display: inline-block;*/
        height: 131.125px;
        line-height: 20.799999237060547px;
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 307px;
        background-color: none;
    }

    ul.nav {
        height: 151px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    .nav li  {
        border-top-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        display: block;
        height: 43.375px;
        line-height: 20.799999237060547px;
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: visible;
        overflow-y: visible;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        width: 307px;
        background-color: none;
    }

    .nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .nav li a:hover {
        background-color: #fff; 
    }

    /* End navigation bar styling. */
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#Personal" data-ajax="false">Personal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Orgnization" data-ajax="false">Orgnization</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Additional" data-ajax="false">Additional</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Thank You

Comment: you want to wrap the full list and not the singel elements at all?

Comment: Yes. Kind of like Inset in http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/listviews/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6zs2V/1/

**CSS**

```
    ul.nav {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-left-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border-top-right-radius: 9.600000381469727px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    }



    .nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 11px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000;

        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
```

Comment: The border isnt wrapped around the whole list and the white space is still under each element though. Why? Thank You!

Comment: White space is the border. don't you want to distinguish between li's ?

Comment: So how would i make it the same color as the other border. And if you look at the edges, the other border isnt correct on the edges of the list. :/